Handling deadlock between two transactions
Using Postgres and Jooq to generate SQL queries
I have two transactions that can run parallelly, each has query
INSERT INTO <TABLE> ... ON CONFLICT(SESSION_ID, PARTITION_DATE) UPDATE SET ....

Error message is :

Detail: Process 2180251 waits for ShareLock on transaction 115843117; blocked by process 2180250.\nProcess 2180250 waits for ShareLock on transaction 115843119; blocked by process 2180251.\n  Hint: See server log for query details.\n  Where: while inserting index tuple (124241,1) in relation "table_p2024_11_27"

I could only think of following situation that is causing the above deadlock,
When two transactions run parallelly and they face conflict on same SESSION_ID, PARTITION_DATE combination, I am facing deadlock. I can understand this like

T1 and T2 both acquire shared lock to check whether on-conflict occurs or not, but when they both have on-conflict both T1 and T2 try to acquire Exclusive lock, so they need to remove all the shared locks by other transactions, T1 waiting for T2 to remove shared lock and T2 is waiting for T1 to remove shared lock. Hence a deadlock.

Can you tell me any solutions apart from

retrying the transaction
using an in-mem db for holding the transactions at application level

pls refer the following pastebin link for Steps to recreate:
https://p.ip.fi/Ijua

Hint: See server log for query details.

Don't run the queries in parallel.

Retrying the transaction is the right answer. There may be other ways, but you are not showing enough of your statement.

@AdrianKlaver can't avoid that we are having multiple pods in production for high availability

@LaurenzAlbe, we are having 3 types of events register, deRegister, matchFound. We want to capture the data in a single row(it tracks the userSession). Our analytics service can recieve these events out of order(u can get match-found before register), to capture them in same row we are using session_id, two events of same session id will update the same row. if there is no sessionId then we insert row with sessionId, if it is already present we try to update the row using on-conflict. Hope this gives u full context

No, it doesn't, because that was text, not SQL.

@LaurenzAlbe, my bad. please refer the following link I tried my best to give you the entire context in the paste bin link: https://p.ip.fi/Ijua . I am using batching

The question needs to be self-contained. Please put the relevant code into the question.
